# Vectorized solution to find uninterrupted attendance streaks

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I've got a longitudinal survey where participants are invited every year. In some years they fail to take part, and sometimes they pass away.  I need to identify which participants have taken part for a consistent 'streak' since the start of the survey (i.e. if they stop, they stop for good).

I've done this with a 'for' loop, which works fine in the example below. But I have many years and many participants, and iterating over each row is very slow. Is there another approach that I could use that eliminates the need for looping over all the rows? I also thought about using `apply` but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

In the example, `TRUE` means they participated in that year. The loop creates two vectors - `finalyear` for the last year they took part, and `streak` to show if they completed all years before the `finalyear` (i.e. cases 1, 3 and 5).

```
dat <- data.frame(ids = 1:5, "1999" = c(T, T, T, F, T), 
                             "2000" = c(T, F, T, F, T), 
                             "2001" = c(T, T, T, T, T), 
                             "2002" = c(F, T, T, T, T), 
                             "2003" = c(F, T, T, T, F))
finalyear <- NULL
streak <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {

    x <- as.numeric(dat[i,2:6])
    y <- max(grep(1, x))

    finalyear[i] <- y
    streak[i] <- sum(x) == y

}

dat$finalyear <- finalyear
dat$streak <- streak
```

Comment: Lots of answers - anyone want to create a larger dataset and benchmark them? How big is the dataset so its possible to make a representative test set for benchmarking?

Comment: There are about 250,000 cases and 25 years. All of the answers below solve my problem - thanks everyone! If people are interested, I could make a representative dataset for testing different approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `max.col` and `rowSums` as a `vectorized` approach.

```
dat$finalyear <- max.col(dat[-1], 'last')
```

If there are rows without `TRUE` values, we can make sure to return 0 for that row by multiplying with the double negation of `rowSums`.  The `FALSE` will be coerced to 0 and multiplying with 0 returns 0 for that row.

```
dat$finalyear <- max.col(dat[-1], 'last')*!!rowSums(dat[-1])
```

Then, we create the 'streak' column by comparing the `rowSums` of columns 2:6 with that of 'finalyear'

```
dat$streak <-  rowSums(dat[,2:6])==dat$finalyear
dat
#   ids X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 finalyear streak
#1   1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE         3   TRUE
#2   2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5  FALSE
#3   3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5   TRUE
#4   4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5  FALSE
#5   5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE         4   TRUE
```

Or a one-line code (it could fit in one-line, but decided to make it obvious by 2-lines ) suggested by @ColonelBeauvel

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(dat, finalyear=max.col(dat[-1], 'last'), 
            streak=rowSums(dat[-1])==finalyear)
```

Comment: one liner with `mutate(dat, finalyear=max.col(dat[-1], 'last'), streak=rowSums(dat[-1])==finalyear)`

Answer (score 4):

For-loops are not inherently bad in R, but they are slow if you grow vectors iteratively (like you are doing). There are often better ways to do things. Example of a solution with only apply-functions:

```
dat$finalyear <- apply(dat[,2:6],MARGIN=1,function(x){max(which(x))})
dat$streak <-  apply(dat[,2:7],MARGIN=1,function(x){sum(x[1:5])==x[6]})
```

Or option 2, based on comment by @Spacedman:

```
dat$finalyear <- apply(dat[,2:6],MARGIN=1,function(x){max(which(x))})
dat$streak <-  apply(dat[,2:6],MARGIN=1,function(x){max(which(x))==sum(x)})

> dat
  ids X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 finalyear streak
1   1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE         3   TRUE
2   2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5  FALSE
3   3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5   TRUE
4   4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         5  FALSE
5   5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE         4   TRUE
```

Comment: Neat, but beware it depends on `finalyear` being added on directly after the true/false data, in this case in column 7.

Comment: Thanks. I doubted whether I should do it this way, or call max(which(x)) twice. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
gather(data = dat,year,value,-ids) %>%
  mutate(year=as.integer(gsub("X","",year))) %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  summarize(finalyear=last(year[value]),
            streak=!any(value[first(year):finalyear] == FALSE))
```

output

```
  ids finalyear streak
1   1      2001   TRUE
2   2      2003  FALSE
3   3      2003   TRUE
4   4      2003  FALSE
5   5      2002   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base version using `apply` to loop over rows and `rle` to see how often the state changes. Your condition seems to be equivalent to the state starting as `TRUE` and only ever changing to `FALSE` at most once, so I test the `rle` as being shorter than 3 and the first value being `TRUE`:

```
> dat$streak = apply(dat[,2:6],1,function(r){r[1] & length(rle(r)$length)<=2})
> 
> dat
  ids X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 streak
1   1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   TRUE
2   2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
3   3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE
4   4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
5   5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   TRUE
```

There's probably loads of ways of working out `finalyear`, this just finds the last element of each row which is `TRUE`:

```
> dat$finalyear = apply(dat[,2:6], 1, function(r){max(which(r))})
> dat
  ids X1999 X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 streak finalyear
1   1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   TRUE         3
2   2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE         5
3   3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE         5
4   4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE         5
5   5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   TRUE         4
```